# Programmatically changing width or height not working for Mac app

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstableview

I have a very strange issue. I need to programmatically increase my TableView height. But programmatic frame change in terms of width or height isn't been aplied. Is there some other way of changing frames in Cocoa?

I’m using the following code:

```
-(IBAction )topButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    if(testView.isHidden == NO){
        [testView setHidden:YES];
        [tableView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,595, 666,595+120)];
}
    else {
        [tableView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,595, 666,595)];
        [testView setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question added the image for tableview please have a look

Comment: Even if I try for NSView instead of tableview still I m nt able to edit its frame through code

Comment: Thanx Bavarious ! it worked.I changed the frame of scrollview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, a table view is enclosed in a scroll view and the scroll view is configured to automatically resize its subviews. This means that changing the table view frame alone won’t work because the enclosing scroll view will autoresize it.

You should change the frame of the enclosing scroll view instead. For example:

```
[[tableView enclosingScrollView] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,595, 666,595+120)];
```

or you could have an outlet for the scroll view:

```
[tableScrollView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,595, 666,595+120)];
```

Comment: can u answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607074/get-the-row-number-of-the-tableview-on-single-tap-in-mac-app

Comment: c an u answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813940/problem-using-autolayout-feature-of-mac-os-lion