# Get the row number of the tableView on single tap in mac app

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a mac app that uses tableView that has some rows.On taping(single tap ) a particular row, I want that row number.Actually , I want to set the value of the label based on the row number selected.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table delegate can implement `- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)row;`

Seems like that'll give you the row you want, then just return "YES" to allow the selection.

Or your delegate could implement `- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;` and then get the currently selected cell (though if you allow multiple selection this might not be sufficient).