# Problem using autolayout feature of Mac os Lion

Tags: cocoa, macos, touch

I am using autolayout feature for my mac app.I have enabled autolayout for my mainWindow & also for its child views.But on expanding window , only my window expands in size but not the child views.And on app launch I get following message in the console

"Layout still needs update after calling -[WebHTMLView layout].  WebHTMLView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed."

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log is probably not related to your issue.

For your issue, select a view that you expect to stay pinned to the side of your window but isn't.  You should see the constraints involving that view drawn as blue.  It'll stay pinned if and only if you see a constraint there that pins it.  You can explicitly add constraints with the Editor > Align and Editor > Pin menus.

The log is because web view implements that method and needs to rev, but it's mostly[1] harmless.

[1] Possibly html layout in the web view ends up triggering more often than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if

> WebHTMLView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout
>   without calling super.

like the error text explains? `WebHTMLView` is your class?

As they say:

> The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa Autolayout
>   class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.