# Autolayout warning in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, autolayout

I am getting a warning I do not fully understand every time I run my app:

`Layout still needs update after calling -[WebHTMLView layout].  WebHTMLView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.`

(I've seen this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813940/problem-using-autolayout-feature-of-mac-os-lion), yet the answer provided solves some other issue, thus my question.) The warning appears as soon as I add a web view to my app. What does it mean, and how should I fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `- (void)layout` is implemented in `WebHTMLView`. The source for WebKit is available on Apple's open source page to review.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7534.53.11/mac/WebView/WebHTMLView.mm

In the Auto Layout documentation, it states that you only need to implement "layout" if you need custom logic to layout subviews while using Auto Layout. It goes on to say that you should always call `[super layout]` in your custom implementation.  That is not happening with `WebHTMLView`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/layout

This message can *probably* be safely ignored for your project. The same thing happens for me on a blank new project.

Comment: Is there a Radar item for this?

Comment: I got that with a simple NSTableView while dragging an item. I have not implemented any Layout method. So this pretty smells like a bug in Apple's Swifty Cocoa implementation. Radar? I guess not. I still have more than half a dozen open compiler bugs reported not even being touched by Apple yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

Besides the noted `NSTableView` with dragging I found out that if you open the `NSFontManager` this will always show this message. Not only with Swift but also with Apple's own demo program CoreTextArcCocoa. So it's definitely some bug in Apple's guts.

Comment: To:Thomas, maybe it comes from NSFontPanel instead of NSFontManager.

Comment: @JiulongZhao Sure, it's the font panel which pops up from the Edit menu.