# Auto Layout Warning with WebView in Lion (but Not Mountain Lion)

Tags: autolayout

When using WebView with Auto Layout in Lion, I get the following warning:

Layout still needs update after calling -[WebHTMLView layout].
WebHTMLView or one of its superclasses may have overridden 
-layout without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied 
layout in the middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in 
Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some 
pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.

This thread explains why: [Autolayout warning in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958576/autolayout-warning-in-mac-os-x?lq=1)

In Mountain Lion (MacBook Pro, 13-inch, mid-2009), the problem disappears—so why is it still happening on my Lion machine (Mac Pro1,1 2006)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a annoying but benign log. It's unavoidable, but harmless, and it doesn't mean you're doing anything wrong.